# How do I make the find reverse method to continue moving?

Tags: vb.net, replace

I am currently able to search through some text and find the first matching string. This moves from left to right, and each time "btnFindNext" is clicked, the next matching string is selected.

However, I now want to make it possible so that the search moves from right to left. I am using the RichTextBoxFind.Reverse method, and indeed this selects the first matching string from the right. However, when the user clicks "btnFindNext" again, the next matching string is not selected. Any ideas why?

Edit: I've added the code I am currently using to select from left to right.

The user first presses 'Find' and this is the code.

```
 startFrom = RichTextBox.Find(textToFind.Text,
 RichTextBox.SelectionStart, RichTextBoxFinds.None)

If lastposition <> -1 Then
RichTextBox.SelectionStart = startFrom
RichTextBox.SelectionLength = textToFind.Text.Length
startFrom = startFrom + 1
    Else
        MsgBox(cboFFindWhat.Text & " Not Found")
    End If
```

The user then presses 'FindNext'. This is the code for that.

```
startFrom = RichTextBox.Find(textToFind.Text, startFrom, RichTextBoxFinds.None)
If startFrom <> -1 Then
RichTextBox.SelectionStart = startFrom
RichTextBox.SelectionLength = textToFind.text.length
startFrom = startFrom + 1
Else
MsgBox(textToFind.Text & " Not Found")
End If
```

The above 2 sections of code work perfectly for searching down a document. I now want to make it possible so that the user can search upwards. How is this achieved?
Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I've edited my question and involved my code for the selection from left to right.

Comment: Have yo looked at [create-a-find-form-for-a-richtextbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837331/how-do-i-create-a-find-form-for-a-richtextbox) See the second answer. If that does not help you post the code for the reverse part.

Comment: Hi Pat, I've tried the second answer and it doesn't work for me. My code is the same for the reverse part. I believe the code I uploaded has an error, I'll update it. The code within my question is the code I am using for the normal find. How would I turn this into the reverse?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for the reverse part. Each time you run it, it find the previous occurrence. (Then when you get to the beginning it starts again.)

```
Dim start As Integer
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If start = 0 Then start = RichTextBox1.Text.Length
    start = RichTextBox1.Find("findme", 0, start, RichTextBoxFinds.Reverse)
    MessageBox.Show(start.ToString)
End Sub
```